# How to configure WSO2 IS for Windows Authentication and multi-domain Active Directory configuration?

Tags: ldap, windows-authentication, wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 Identity Server 5.2.0.
At one of our client site we have a scenario where we need to authenticate users against 2 Active Directory (LDAP) domains.
We have also enabled IWA (Integrated Windows Authentication) in this setup.
Can you please let us know how the WSO2 IS configuration should be done for this scenario?

We have gone through the WSO2 IS doc which describes how to configure multiple user stores in user-mgt.xml file but it looks like it works properly without Integrated Windows Authentication (IWA) where login page is displayed to the user and user has option to specify domain name in-front of user name but it seems not working in IWA case.

Can you please let us know how to handle this scenario? Please point us to documentation which describes this configuration.

Can multi domain authentication work with IWA?

Comment: Are these two domain entirely different domains or sub domains?

Comment: Those are entirely different domains and two way trust is enabled between them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WSO2 IS 5.3.0 - IWA authentication option not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506106/wso2-is-5-3-0-iwa-authentication-option-not-available)

Answer (score 0):

IWA utilizes NTLM to authenticate users based on an encrypted ticket/message passed between a browser and a server. You need to configure an external trust between two Active Directory domains in order to make NTLM token exchange work properly.

Following article [1] gives a detailed guide to setup IWA authentication for a multiple windows domains environment with WSO2 Identity Server 5.2.0.

[1] https://ashenweerathunga.wordpress.com/2017/02/03/configuring-iwa-single-sign-on-for-multiple-windows-domains-with-wso2-identity-server

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Our client have created AD forest and enabled the 2 way trust between the domains. As per above post that you have shared, we need not to configure two UserStoreManager (two domain) in WSO2. It will just connect to one domain only but because of trust the users from other domain will be validated. Is my assumption true? Please guide.

Comment: Do we need to create any group in domain 1 with the users of domain 2 so that the authentication will work? We are getting following error while accessing the URL from machine from domain 2. From the WSO2 logs we are able to see that the user from domain 2 is trying to login but the authentication is failing.

Comment: TID: [-1234] [] [2018-01-17 14:17:24,881] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.iwa.servlet.IWAServlet} - Successfully logged in user: Domain2\Q010101
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-01-17 14:17:25,362] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler} - Authentication Failed
  at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.iwa.IWAAuthenticator.processAuthenticationResonse(IWAAuthenticator.java:111)

Comment: please attach full exception in debug mode.